# Comparing different Enums in generic <TEnum> class

Tags: c#, generics, enums, wrapper

I am trying to build a wrapper class to store any enum. It should then be able to compare 2 different wrapper of different enum types.

```
public class SmartEnum<TEnum> where TEnum : System.Enum
{
    public TEnum Enum;

    public SmartEnum(TEnum Enum)
    {
        this.Enum = Enum;
    }

    public bool Equals(SmartEnum<TEnum> smartEnum)
    {
        var aType = Enum.GetType();
        var bType = smartEnum.Enum.GetType();
        
        if(aType != bType)
            return false;

        return (int)(object)(Enum) == (int)(object)(smartEnum.Enum);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I call the Equals method on enum A and pass enum B it defauls to using object.Equals instead:

```
    SmartEnum<Color> red = new SmartEnum<Color>(Color.RED);
    SmartEnum<Color> green = new SmartEnum<Color>(Color.GREEN);
    SmartEnum<Car> car = new SmartEnum<Car>(Car.SUZUKI);
    
    red.Equals(green); <-- Works
    red.Equals(car) <-- Actually calls object.Equals
```

I understand that because SmartEnum is generic and Equals is not, it expects to receive the same type as the class instance.

If anyone knows how to do it or has a better way to compare different enums I would appreciate it :)

I tried to play around making it `Equals<SmartEnum>` or `Equals<T>` and use "where TEnum : SmartEnum but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to make this work:

1.

```
public bool Equals<T>(T smartEnum) where T : SmartEnum<TEnum>
```

This results in:

```
The type 'SmartEnum<SmartEnumTestUnit.Car>' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'SmartEnum<SmartEnumTestUnit.Color>.Equals<T>(T)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'SmartEnum<SmartEnumTestUnit.Car>' to 'SmartEnum<SmartEnumTestUnit.Color>'
```

2. 

```
public bool Equals<SmartEnum>(SmartEnum<TEnum> smartEnum) where SmartEnum : SmartEnum<TEnum>
```

This results in defaulting to object.Equals

3.

```
public bool Equals<T>(T smartEnum) where T : TEnum
```

Finally results in:

```
red.Equals<Car>(car) 
The type 'SmartEnumTestUnit.Car' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'SmartEnum<SmartEnumTestUnit.Color>.Equals<T>(T)'. There is no boxing conversion from 'SmartEnumTestUnit.Car' to 'SmartEnumTestUnit.Color'.
```

Comment: Add an override for `object.Equals(object)` to your class.

Comment: What does it mean for two different enum types to be "equal" ? Doesn't just using the native enum already do everything you want here, but with the advantage of being at compile time rather than runtime? What is the point of this type? I don't mean this rudely; in order to provide a meaningful answer, it kinda needs a clear intent

Comment: Looks like you want to equate enums by their **numeric value**, but your code won't always work because not all enums have the same underlying type of `int`. As shown in the [language definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/enums#192-enum-declarations) enums can be based on any numeric type other than `char`.  So one enum could have underlying type `unsigned long` while another has `short`.  `(int)(object)(Enum)` will throw in such a case. How do you want to equate such enums, especially when one might be signed and the other, not?

Comment: @MarcGravell The expectation that different enum types will be unequal and only the same type and value will be equal. As far as I can tell I can't comare native enums of different types, right?

Comment: @dbc that's a good point, I can equate for GetUnderlyingType as well to avoid this.

I added an explanation of my intention as a comment on Guru Stron's answer if you want to take a look and give your opinion on my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you want to do this, but one of the attempts was quite close, purely from technical perspective try the following:

```cs
public bool Equals<T>(SmartEnum<T> smartEnum) where T:Enum
{
    // ...
}
```

This declares `Equals` with generic parameter `T` which should be enum and restricts the incoming `smartEnum` parameter to `SmartEnum<T>`.

Note that `T` here just a generic parameter name, as `SmartEnum` in:

```cs
public bool Equals<SmartEnum>(SmartEnum<TEnum> smartEnum) where SmartEnum : SmartEnum<TEnum>
```

Which results in quite interesting behavior here due to names matching (`SmartEnum` in `Equals<SmartEnum>` and `where SmartEnum :`  is parameter name, `SmartEnum` in `SmartEnum<TEnum> smartEnum` and `: SmartEnum<T` is the enclosing generic type)

But in general you might want to override `object.Equals(object)` and possibly implement `IEquatable<SmartEnum<TEnum>>`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I confirm that making this change allowed me to achieve what I was looking for.

I have different classes of Enemies, each with their own custom enums. They all send messages to a class the functions as a Squad that then distributes to other members of it.

I don't want Squad the know about all enums and I don't want to create a long enum to be used by every enemy.

Until now it worked with converting the enums to string and parsing them back but I wanted something more performant. Now I also realise I have no way of passing vars without declaring them anyway smh..